# Data files for android local tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4

I've got an android application with a module performing data processing (HTML scraping in fact). This part is pure java and all its tests are in the `src/test` path.

My particular problem is that I have a set of (large-ish) files to be parsed by the tests and I need a reliable way to access these files. I know that best practice would be to keep the files inline, but dumping 300k-ish content in strings is not ideal.

I've [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898634/how-to-provide-data-files-for-android-unit-tests) [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777394/android-local-tests-vs-instrumented-test) [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341744/android-studio-unit-testing-read-data-input-file) sources and I'd like to know if there is an alternative to the [gradle trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341744/android-studio-unit-testing-read-data-input-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me by placing all the test files in `src/test/resources` and accessing them via:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(path);
```

where `path` is the relative path to `src/test/resources`.

With the current arrangement (AS 2.0.0-beta6, gradle 2.10), the resources are copied into `build/intermediates/sourceFolderJavaResources`.